# chain rule with differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, chain-rule

My [textbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHaC0.png) had 
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(x+y+e^{xy}\right)=1+\frac{dy}{dx}+e^{xy}\left(y+x\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$$
 as part of an example problem.

Why does
$\frac{d}{dx}(e^{xy})$ equal $e^{xy}(y+x\frac{dy}{dx})$?

Why does it not simply equal $ye^{xy}$ ?

Is there something about the chain rule I am missing?

Comment: Hint : Try this first 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d}{dx} (xy) = ?
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product rule:
$$\frac{d}{dx}(uv)=u\frac{dv}{dx}+v\frac{du}{dx}$$

So we need to find $\frac{d}{dx}(e^{xy})$.

We know that
$$\frac{d}{dx}(e^{xy})=\frac{d}{dx}(xy)\cdot e^{xy}$$

Letting $u=x$ and $v=y$, can you proceed from here?

Comment: Your first expression is an application of the [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule) rather than the chain rule

Comment: @Henry oh my I'm so sorry. Edited! Thanks for pointing out.